# Cinder: max_over_subscription_ratio ignored

Tags: openstack, cinder

I have set

```
max_over_subscription_ratio = 1.0
```

in the [DEFAULT] section of cinder.conf, but when I do

```
cinder get-pools --detail
```

it shows

```
[...]
| max_over_subscription_ratio | 20.0
[...]
```

What could be wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cinder's [sample configuration](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/_static/cinder.conf.sample) puts this setting in the `[backend_defaults]` section. Alternatively, the [oversubscription page](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/admin/blockstorage-over-subscription.html) says that you can also put it in a specific backend's section, but `[DEFAULT]` is not the right place.